# html lang tag not working with google translater

Tags: html, google-translate

I have to show a html page in french. the [page](http://www.tudor-tea.com/lan/) .

I have use the HTML tag like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="fr" xml:lang="fr">
```

I have used the google translater in my page.First time When I place this It was automatically changed whole page into French. Now not working please help.

Answer (score 3):

HTML has no facilities to automatically translate content. The `lang` attribute means "The content of this element is written in this language". (This is used as a pronunciation guide for text to speech software, and as a hint to automated translation software that takes HTML as input).

The only sensible approaches to translating content for the WWW are:

- Use the services of a professional translator and then place their work on another URL
- Let users make use of automated translation services if they encounter text written in a language they do not understand (some browsers, such as Google Chrome, will offer to run content through these services automatically).

Automated translation is not very good, so you should not present it to end users yourself. It implies that the poor translation is something that you think is good enough to publish (it won't be).

Comment: Thanks... I i have added a small note on my question please check again !!

Comment: Google Translator should expect the input HTML to have lang attributes that say what the content is, not what you want it to be. If you are saying "This content is written in French" then it isn't surprising that it wouldn't try to translate it into French.

Comment: First day when I put like this was working !! Now its not working ... is there any idea about that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way you call the Google translator. The `pageLanguage` property specifies the *source* language, so it must be `en`. (It could also be omitted, but then the translator would start making its guesses.) The *destination* languags(s) are to be specified in the `includedLanguages` property. To fix French as the destination language, you would use `fr` there. If the code

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'fr', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,autoDisplay: false, includedLanguages: ''}, 'google_translate_element');}
```

is thus replaced by

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement(
    {pageLanguage: 'en',
     layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
     autoDisplay: false, includedLanguages: 'fr'},
    'google_translate_element');}
```

then the page appears with a widget for translation from English to (broken) French. If you leave `includedLanguages` to the empty value `''`, there will be a menu of destination languages in the widget. That’s the closest you can get I suppose; it seems to be Google’s intention that the translation works via user actions.
(**Original text, mistaken:**
then the page is automatically translated from English to (broken) French. You may wish to set `#google_translate_element { display: none }` in CSS then, since the translate widget is of no use and just confuses people. Alternatively, if you leave `includedLanguages` to the empty value `''`, Google translate will generate a language menu for the user.)

I strongly support Quentin’s advice on avoiding automatic translation of web pages, at least when used this way. Google translate produces translations that may look OK on the surface, and some sentences may look rather good, but it also produces incomprehensible mixes of words and, worse still, translations that look fairly good but have the content all wrong (though this worst case is not as common as it used to be, as they have presumable tuned their technologies).

Comment: Thanks. I have changed my code how you mention above but still not working.

Comment: Sorry, my code snippets were confused and did not match the explanation I gave; fixed it now. In the `googleTranslateElementInit` function, the essential setting is `pageLanguage: 'en'`.

Comment: Hi, the page is automatically not translated from English to French... I dono whats wrong on this  http://www.tudor-tea.com/lan/

Comment: @Wazan, it seems that you cannot make it more automatic. My tests seemed to suggest that it was possible, but this was apparently a wrong conclusion – because I tested after having selected a translation and then returning to the page or refreshing it, in which case the old selection still had an effect. I presume it is Google’s intent that translation works via user actions.

Answer (score -1):

Sir you enter DOCTYPE for HTML4...
html lang attribute will work normally with html doctype.
Try it :
`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: The Doctype in the question is XHTML 1.0 Transitional, the Doctype in your answer is HTML 5, there is no sign of an HTML 4 Doctype anywhere … and the lang attribute is supported in `text/html` documents regardless of the of the Doctype.